# Visual Studio C# Web API Project code in class not executed

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api

I am new to the C# community. I created a controller and a class with the class containing some logic from a COM reference that I want to be executed.

When I call the API, it does not seem to be going into the ImportInventory method and no logic is executed in that public string (as seen from the debugging breakpoints).

Can someone please assist on how to get this part of the code executed? I am new to C# and can't seem to find the issue.

Code snippet of the controller:

```
using MDRDS_PastelIntegrator.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace MDRDS_PastelIntegrator.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class InventoryController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<InventoryController> _logger;

        public InventoryController(ILogger<InventoryController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpPost(Name = "POSTInventory")]
        public IEnumerable<POSTInventory> Get(string pParameter, string pPath)
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 1).Select(index => new POSTInventory
            {
                Parameter = pParameter,
                Path = pPath
            })
            .ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Code snippet of the class:

```
namespace MDRDS_PastelIntegrator.Models
{
    public class POSTInventory
    {
        //public string? StrReturn;

        public string? Parameter { get; set; }
        public string? Path { get; set; }

        public string ImportInventory(string Parameter, string Path)
        {
            var SDK = new PasSDK.PastelPartnerSDK();

            //Set License
            var F_GetLisence = new SetLicense();
            F_GetLisence.MethodSetLicense();

            //Set Data Path
            var StrReturn = SDK.SetDataPath(Path);

            if (StrReturn == "0")
            {
                var StrIn = Parameter;
                var StrCodeIn = StrIn;

                //Import Inventory Item
                StrReturn = SDK.ImportInventory(StrIn);
            };

            //Blank return string - No serial number
            if (StrReturn.Length == 0)
            {
                StrReturn = "Serial Number Not Specified.";
                //return StrReturn;
            };

            //Get Result Code
            if (StrReturn == "0")
            {
                StrReturn = "0 = Success";
            }
            else
            {
                StrReturn = "1 = Unsuccessfull";
            };

            return StrReturn;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you even calling ImportInventory method?

Answer (score 0):

You create an object POSTInventory but you never call the ImportInventory method of this object

Comment: Consider adding a helpful example of how to call the method.